# How to dbms_output.put_line the UTL_HTTP.req object?

Tags: web-services, http, plsql

I have a scenario where PLSQL package UTL_HTTP API is being used to make Webservice calls to Global Payment Gateway API (GPI Atlanta). The goal is certify against their newly upgraded API.

It goes well on other operations until we hit a particular operation which used to work fine until Global decided to upgrade their back end. Since then we are getting 'Invalid Login Attempt' response for that operation.

I am looking for the Request payload to get an idea what is going on.
How to print UTL_HTTP.req?

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more details? Are you invoking utl_http.get_response and it's returning "Invalid Login Attempt"?

UTL_HTTP.req specs:

```
  TYPE req IS RECORD (
    url                    VARCHAR2(32767 byte), -- Requested URL
    method                 VARCHAR2(64),    -- Requested method
    http_version           VARCHAR2(64),    -- Requested HTTP version
    private_hndl           PLS_INTEGER      -- For internal use only
  );
```

Comment: Yes I am invoking utl_http.get_response and it's returning "Invalid Login Attempt". Also I checked the Request payload, the userId and password matches with what I have been given by Global.

Comment: I suggest you to start with some other tool e.g. SoapUI and see if it works with given credentials. Then you can be sure that it's about you plsql code which is not working correctly.

Comment: And also if the web service is secured (HTTPS) you need to handle it differently: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/utl_http-and-ssl.php

Comment: I found the root cause after comparing the 2 WSDL files: production and certapi ones. It is found certapi differs in the GlobalUserName usage, now they use it as GlobalUsername, notice the case difference. That is why it was giving that error. I have notified Global and they are working to get it fixed on their side. Thanks